# How to accurately take the highest value between two columns while accounting for several missing values in other columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I create a data frame below that represents individuals within households (`hid`). I assign them a social class (`class`) measure coded from 1 to 4. The column `relation` represents the head of the household (coded as 0) and the partner (coded as 1). The column `cntry` represents different countries: UK, US. The column `did` represents country-years: US 2008, US 2009, UK 2008, UK 2009.

I would like to create a new column to take the highest social class among both partners. I have done that but I still have some issues in the output.

Main issue: if individuals have missing values for their household id (`hid`), the code assigns them the highest value automatically. I would like to keep these individuals in the data frame, and also leave them with their original social class. See household id number 3. The original class column is coded as 3 but gets assigned 4, even though we don't know what the social class is of other people in the household because it is missing.

Could someone help please?

Replication code:

```
library(missForest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Create Variables
class <- sample(1:4, 10000, replace = TRUE)
hid <- rep(1:(10000/2), each = 2) 
relation <-  rep(0:1, 10000/2)
did <- rep(sample(2006:2009, 10000/2, replace = TRUE), each = 2)
cntry <- sample(c("US", "UK"), 10000, replace = TRUE)

# Combine into a data frame
df <- data.frame(class = class,
                 hid = hid,
                 relation = relation,
                 did = did,
                 cntry = cntry)

df <- prodNA(df, noNA = 0.1)


dominant_class_df <- df %>%     
  drop_na("class")  %>% 
  filter(relation < 3) %>%
  group_by(hid,did) %>%      
  summarise(dominant_class = max(class,na.rm=T)) %>%
  mutate(dominant_class = if_else(is.infinite(dominant_class), NA_real_, dominant_class))

df2 <- df %>%
  left_join(dominant_class_df, by = c("hid", "did"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```r
new_class <- function(x, hid) {
  f <- (seq_along(x) - 1L)%/% 2L
  out <- by(data.frame(x, hid), f, FUN = \(X) {
    y <- X[["x"]]
    hid <- X[["hid"]]
    if(any(!is.na(hid))) {
      if(any(!is.na(y))) {
        m <- max(y, na.rm = TRUE)
        y[!is.na(hid)] <- m
        y
      } else y
    } else c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_)
  })
  out |> unlist() |> unname()
}

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(dominant_class = new_class(class, hid))
head(df2, n = 14L)
#>    class hid relation  did cntry dominant_class
#> 1      3   1        0 2008    UK              3
#> 2      3   1        1 2008    US              3
#> 3      3   2        0   NA    US              3
#> 4      2   2       NA 2009  <NA>              3
#> 5      3  NA        0 2006    UK              3
#> 6      2   3        1 2006    UK              3
#> 7      2   4        0 2009    US              2
#> 8      2   4        1 2009    UK              2
#> 9      3   5        0 2007    US              3
#> 10     1   5        1 2007    US              3
#> 11     4   6        0 2007    US              4
#> 12     2  NA        1 2007    UK              2
#> 13     2   7        0 2008    US              2
#> 14     1   7        1 2008    US              2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it seems to work for some rows but not for others. For example row number 12 is coded 2 as class, and the dominant class is 4 even though the house hold id is missing

Comment: @Jack I cannot reproduce that result, after rerunning my code I get `dominant_class` equal to 4 in row 12.

Comment: @Jack I have extended the output with 4 more  rows, see row 12, `dominant_class` is 4.

Comment: Thanks, row 12 dominant class should not be 4, it should be 2. As the original class is 2 of this person, and the household ID is missing, there is no reason to put it 4. This is my issue with the code

Comment: The code should give any person, the highest class within a household. But if I cannot assign you a household ID for any reason (e.g., missing), then you keep your original class number, and you don't get the highest number 4

Comment: @Jack OK, your last two comments made the question clear, thanks. Edited. See if it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `left_join()` might be causing your issues; do you get your expected outcome if you use `mutate()` instead of `summarise()`?

E.g.

```r
library(missForest)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

class <- sample(1:4, 10000, replace = TRUE)
hid <- rep(1:(10000/2), each = 2) 
relation <-  rep(0:1, 10000/2)
did <- rep(sample(2006:2009, 10000/2, replace = TRUE), each = 2)
cntry <- sample(c("US", "UK"), 10000, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(class = class,
                 hid = hid,
                 relation = relation,
                 did = did,
                 cntry = cntry)
df <- prodNA(df, noNA = 0.1)

dominant_class_df <- df %>%     
  drop_na("class")  %>% 
  filter(relation < 3) %>%
  group_by(hid,did) %>%      
  summarise(dominant_class = max(class,na.rm=T)) %>%
  mutate(dominant_class = if_else(is.infinite(dominant_class), NA_real_, dominant_class))

df2 <- df %>%
  left_join(dominant_class_df, by = c("hid", "did"))

###########

df %>%     
#  drop_na("class") %>% # do you need this?
  filter(relation < 3) %>%
  group_by(hid, did) %>%      
  mutate(dominant_class = ifelse(!is.na(hid), max(class, na.rm = TRUE), class)) %>%
  mutate(dominant_class = ifelse(!is.finite(dominant_class), NA, dominant_class)) %>%
  print(n = 25)
#> Warning: There were 308 warnings in `mutate()`.
#> The first warning was:
#> ℹ In argument: `dominant_class = ifelse(!is.na(hid), max(class, na.rm = TRUE),
#>   class)`.
#> ℹ In group 16: `hid = 14`, `did = NA`.
#> Caused by warning in `max()`:
#> ! no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#> ℹ Run `dplyr::last_dplyr_warnings()` to see the 307 remaining warnings.
#> # A tibble: 8,994 × 6
#> # Groups:   hid, did [5,417]
#>    class   hid relation   did cntry dominant_class
#>    <int> <int>    <int> <int> <chr>          <dbl>
#>  1     3     1        0  2008 UK                 3
#>  2     3     1        1  2008 US                 3
#>  3     3     2        0    NA US                 3
#>  4     3    NA        0  2006 UK                 3
#>  5     2     3        1  2006 UK                 2
#>  6     2     4        0  2009 US                 2
#>  7     2     4        1  2009 UK                 2
#>  8     3     5        0  2007 US                 3
#>  9     1     5        1  2007 US                 3
#> 10     4     6        0  2007 US                 4
#> 11     2    NA        1  2007 UK                 2
#> 12     2     7        0  2008 US                 2
#> 13     1     7        1  2008 US                 2
#> 14     2     8        0  2009 UK                 3
#> 15     3     8        1  2009 US                 3
#> 16     4     9        0  2007 UK                 4
#> 17    NA     9        1  2007 US                 4
#> 18     3    10        0  2008 US                 3
#> 19     3    10        1    NA UK                 3
#> 20     1    11        0  2006 UK                 4
#> 21     4    11        1  2006 <NA>               4
#> 22     1    NA        0  2008 UK                 1
#> 23     1    12        1  2008 US                 1
#> 24     1    NA        0  2007 UK                 1
#> 25     3    13        1  2007 UK                 3
#> # ℹ 8,969 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks or the help, i was wondering why the code you provided drops around 1031 observations? Is there a way to avoid dropping these observations?

Comment: That's due to your `filter(relation < 3)` command @Jack; if you comment out that line, or change it to `filter(relation < 3 | is.na(relation))` you get back to 10k observations.

Answer (score 0):

another approach: supply new HIDs for `NA`-HIDs:

```
df  <- df |> mutate(hid = ifelse(is.na(hid),
                                 sprintf('row_%s', row_number()), 
                                 sprintf('hid_%s', hid))
                    )
```

... create `dominant_class_df` as before ...

result:

```
> dominant_class_df |> filter(hid == 'hid_3')
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   hid [1]
  hid     did dominant_class
  <chr> <int>          <dbl>
1 hid_3  2006              2
```